# How to compile for the Erlang VM

Tags: compiler-construction, erlang, leex, yecc

I'm trying to implement a small description language for user scripting in an application. Basically users describe how objects are created from other objects. (Not really a programming language). I could use JSON as well (but it would be more verbose).

I use leex and yecc and i have a decent parse tree. Say it is something like this :

```
{def,double,   %% function name double
    [{x}],     %% list of input names
    %% return expression, in this case {Operator, Operand1, Operand2}
    {'*',{var,x},{number,2}} 
}.
```

With this tree, i would like to build something like this:

```
double(State) ->
    _Var1 = some_app:get_input(State,x),
    _Var1 * 2.
```

But i don't know where to start. I can read the tree at runtime and build funs but i really want to learn how to compile (and hope better performance).

Should i transform my parse tree to Erlang AST and then compile erlang module ?

Thanks.

Comment: found this http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/nano-jfp.pdf

Comment: You might try watching some of Robert Virding's videos.  For instance, [Implemting Languages on the Erlang VM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hry_BUidOAk).  I believe he has at least 2 or 3 videos on similar topics.  Also his [github](https://github.com/rvirding), has several examples of code.  Additionally, you could check out [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) or [Joxa](http://joxa.org/) which are also implemented on the Erlang VM.

Comment: yes i'm taking example on elixir. I've also found [this](http://ninenines.eu/articles/xerl-0.2-two-modules), good infos but very small code compiled. didn't know Joxa, must check this. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the classic workflow is this :

1. Define tokens and build a lexer with `leex`
2. Define a grammar and build a parser with `yecc`
3. Tokenize source code with the lexer
4. Build a parse tree with the parser fed with the tokens
5. Generate core erlang forms module whith `cerl`
6. Compile forms with `compile` module. It can yield beam binaries to load as a module or create a `.beam` file

As an alternative to `leex/yecc` (LALR parser) we can use [neotoma](https://github.com/seancribbs/neotoma) which works with PEG grammars. It depends on what you have to parse. There i needed left recursion and didn't want to handle whitespace.

As a target, the EVM (BEAM) seems quite easy. Compiling ends up to simply translate from one language to another and Core Erlang is a very simple language but still expressive.

Comment: Is there a way to visualize the grammar ? Perhaps something on the lines of https://metacpan.org/pod/GraphViz2::Parse::Yacc

Comment: @TheMitraBoy I think you would have to convert your grammar to a classic Yacc grammar file (or any other popular format). I think I dit that a while ago to generate railway diagrams, but I cannot remember.